# Qt: "Expanding" doesn't work inside a layout

Tags: qt

My purpose is to create a scrollable control with a QVBoxLayout inside of it that has various controls (say buttons) on it. That control is put on a *.ui form. In the constructor for that control I write the following code:

```
    MyScrollArea::MyScrollArea(QWidget *parent) :
        QScrollArea(parent)
    {
        // create the scrollable container

        this->container = new QWidget();  // container widget member
        this->container->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        this->container->setContentsMargins(QMargins(0,0,0,0));

        this->content = new QVBoxLayout(); // layout member
        this->content->setMargin(0);
        this->content->setSpacing(0);

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            QPushButton * widget = new QPushButton();
            widget->setText("button");
            widget->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
            this->content->addWidget(widget);
        }

        this->container->setLayout(this->content);
        this->content->layout();

        this->setWidget(this->container);
   }
```

My **problem**: the buttons have a fixed size and **do not expand horizontally**. they have a fixed size. i'd like them to expand horizontally to fill the row they're in. How can I get them expanding horizontally across their parent container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `this->setWidgetResizable(true);`

Comment: that with "setMinimumHeight" for each widget in the layout did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonGenX No, `setMinimumHeight` does *not* do the trick, it does another trick - the one that is written on the tin :-). It's purely coincident it worked in your case.

Comment: `setWidgetResizable(True)` works like a charm, it has to be called on the `QScrollArea`.